# getElementsByTagName in E4X

Tags: javascript, e4x

I'm searching a possibility to get an array of elements in E4X for an unknown tagname (like the DOMs getElementsByTagName) inside of a function.

My first thought was something like:

```
(function (doc, tag) {
    return doc..[tag];
})
```

Is there any chance to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
doc.descendants(tag);
```

And there's always eval :)

```
var query = "doc.." + tag;
eval(query);
```

Comment: "If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question." - Rasmus Lerdorf, creator of PHP

Comment: "evil is as eval does" - Anurag Mishra